# Data binding between 2 sibling elements

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

Is it possible to pass the bindings from one child to the other child in the parent? The parent doesn't need to use the bindings. It will need to be 2 way.

To put it another way, I need to siblings to share data-bindings.

```
   <app-drawer id="drawer">                                                                                                                                                                                  
     <div class='left-bar-container'>                                                                                                                                                                                        
     <listings-drawer></listings-drawer>
```

---

```
           <!-- Main content -->
    <iron-pages
        selected="[[page]]"
        attr-for-selected="name"
        fallback-selection="view404"
        role="main">
      <my-view1 name="my-view1" form-loading="{{isLoading}}"
        pic="{{pics}}" area-code="{{areaCode}}"></my-view1>
```

I need `<listings-drawer></listings-drawer>` to have access to `form-loading="{{isLoading}}"`, `pic="{{pics}}"`, and `area-code="{{areaCode}}"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<app-drawer id="drawer">                                                                                                                                                                                  
 <div class='left-bar-container'>                                                                                                                                                                                        
 <listings-drawer loading="{{isLoading}}"
    some-pics="{{pics}}" some-area-code="{{areaCode}}"></listings-drawer>
       <!-- Main content -->
<iron-pages
    selected="[[page]]"
    attr-for-selected="name"
    fallback-selection="view404"
    role="main">
  <my-view1 name="my-view1" form-loading="{{isLoading}}"
    pic="{{pics}}" area-code="{{areaCode}}"></my-view1>
```

`

There is no reason the above would not work, assuming those property names were used in the listings-drawer element.

Comment: Thanks! Just to confirm, is this safe to share bindings like this in Polymer? Since I haven't seen anything like this in the documentation, I am not sure if I am working on meant behavior or side effects.

Comment: It's a good question actually. The behavior itself is definitely by design. It is perfectly fine to use same property in multiple bindings. Although I expect there to be a possibility for weirdness when you would frequently update it from both elements. When two-way is unnecessary I would advise binding one-way